# Express/Cors/Apache2 Proxy/Angular - Why is the response ACAO header mismatching the original request origin on some requests?

Tags: angular, apache, express, cors

### Short version :

My API allows my front app to access it through a RegExp origin CORS. My front app has two url, the servername `example.org` and the `www.example.org` alias. (These are accessed with Apache2 proxies, see conf below in detailed version)
When accessing the alias url, some (not all) of the requests fails because the response header ACAO is set to the server name.

This behavior is random and affect only the alias.

This is not an issue where the origin is not allowed or not set, the problem here, is that the request origin header and the response Access-Control-Allow-Origin header are mismatching, even though both are allowed.

I want to understand what is causing this and how can I solve it ? I do not want to bypass it by redirecting the alias traffic to the main server name.

### Detailed version :

My application is a MEAN stack composed of

1. An API running on Node/ExpressJS served with an Apache2 reverse proxy, it is accessible through `api.example.org`. Express use the CORS package and allow origin matching the regular expression : `\https?:\/\/(www\.)?(domain\.com)\`.
2. A front Angular served using ExpressJS (SSR) and also accessed through an Apache2 reverse proxy.
   It is accessed either with `example.org` or `www.example.org`.

The whole thing is dockerized and works fine when ServerAliases are not involved, it's working flawlessly with proxies with no aliases, for example : `/https?:\/\/(test\.example\.org)/` would work fine.

**I'm fully aware that I could just redirect [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) to example.org in my apache proxy.
Now this question is more about understanding why and solving the problem as is, rather than bypassing it.**

When accessing directly through `example.org` and doing a `Ctrl + Shift + R` reload everything works fine.

When accessing through `www.example.org` and doing a `Ctrl + Shift + R` reload :

- Some requests go through as expected and the CORS header are set correctly.
- However some request fails, and the reason is simple enough, on those requests the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set to `example.org` instead of `www.example.org`. There is a mismatch between the origin in the request and the response.

Thus resulting in error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.org/resume' from origin 'https://www.example.org'
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://example.org' 
that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

Request headers :

```
GET /skill HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.org
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36
Origin: https://www.example.org
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://www.example.org/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
If-None-Match: W/"a842-E9TpqbNXZN+BdTdhAMFBa3wtUgs"
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2020 15:24:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.org
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"a842-E9TpqbNXZN+BdTdhAMFBa3wtUgs"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Via: 1.1 api.example.org
```

Could it be caused by an Apache2 proxy misconfiguration ?

What I have tried to troubleshoot :

- Removing compression from both Api and front
- Removing cache interceptor from angular app
- Removing the ProxyVia and ProxyPreserveHost on my Vhost

Here is the cors config on express

```
// Cors initialization :           
private CorsInitialize(): void {
    const corsOptions = {
      origin: /https?:\/\/(www\.)?(example\.org)/
    };
    console.log('Initializing app with cors : ', corsOptions);
    this.expressApp.use(cors(corsOptions));
}
```

Here are my Apache 2 proxy conf :

```
FRONT

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin development@example.org
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias www.example.org
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3005/ Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3005/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.org [OR] RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.org
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin development@example.org
        ServerName example.org
        ServerAlias www.example.org
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3005/ Keepalive=On
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3005/

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.org/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.org/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

API

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin development@example.org
    ServerName api.example.org
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3004/ Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3004/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.example.org
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin development@example.org
        ServerName api.example.org
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3004/ Keepalive=On
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3004/

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.org/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.org/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The question here, is why does this happen ? And what causes this ?

Comment: You might want to try adding a `Vary: Origin` response header

Comment: I didn't add it myself, but it's already present in the response header. I will edit my question  to add the chrome req/res headers.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue today. It doesn't happen when I reverse proxy through nginx, only apache. I also have the Vary header set to Origin (the cors middleware does this automatically). The issue doesn't present on Firefox, just Chrome. It seems to have something to do with Chrome not honoring the Vary header and serving up a cached result with the wrong Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: Scratch that--Firefox has the same cors errors, but recovers more gracefully. The exact same Express app running behind nginx works flawlessly though.

Comment: All my apps on this server runs on Apache2, for now I gave up the alias. I'm dockerizing all my apps for now, I think, I'll traeffik afterward.